# Use two different weights of Google Roboto font

Tags: html, css, fonts

So basically you import the Roboto font with `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:900" rel="stylesheet">`but note the `Roboto:900` part. Would it be possible for me to import both `Roboto:900` and `Roboto:300` on the same web page? I've tried to just use `Roboto` then set the `font-weight` in the css, but it didn't work.

Ideas? Thanks

Side note: `Roboto:900` is bold style, `Roboto:300` is thin style.

Comment: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,900 (when you pick a font in the directory, it'll even ask you which variants you want to use)

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**CSS**

```
.light{
 font-weight:300;
}
.bold{
 font-weight:900;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

When you click 'use' in Google Fonts you can choose as many font weights as you like by ticking the boxes. The more you import the slower your site will become, but 2 font weights should be ok.

Comment: The above only includes standard versions of the font, not italic

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Roboto font in [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto).

Click on "Select [font-weight] +" beside the font weight you want and the site will build the required links for you.

Example:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```